# How to create image with my new jar file in Docker?

Tags: boot2docker

I'm very new to docker and need to deploy jar file into docker. So I have implemented "Hellow World" program and trying to create container as follows but I'm getting "`curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`" error while calling it.

Help me please I have been working on this for 4 days.

Dockerfile:

```
##### Version: 0.0.1
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER Siva "siva@example.com"

RUN apt-get update
#### installing JDK

RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk

ADD dockertest.jar /usr/share/java/

EXPOSE 8089
```

Build command:

```
sudo docker build -t="img33/img33" .
```

Launching the container from image:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 80 --name imgcon33 img33/img33
```

For reference

```
docker@boot2docker:~/jardeploy$ sudo docker build -t="img33/img33" .

Successfully built f602b747548a

docker@boot2docker:~/jardeploy$ sudo docker run -it -p 80 --name imgcon33 img33/img33

root@21df09a79175:/# exit

docker@boot2docker:~/jardeploy$ docker ps -l

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
21df09a79175        img33/img33:latest   "/bin/bash"         14 seconds ago      Exited (0) 9 seconds ago                       imgcon33

docker@boot2docker:~/jardeploy$ docker start 21df09a79175

21df09a79175

docker@boot2docker:~/jardeploy$ docker ps -l

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                             NAMES
21df09a79175        img33/img33:latest   "/bin/bash"         29 seconds ago      Up 3 seconds        8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49231->80/tcp   imgcon33

docker@boot2docker:~/jardeploy$ curl localhost:49231

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not define port for incomming connections, and boot2docker maps port 80 to the first free high-range port in range 49153 to 65535 (see how to do it [in boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/WORKAROUNDS.md) and [docker](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/)).

Here is the setup that worked for me (on Windows, though, but the same thing is for OSX), I have mapped your application on port 8000, please feel free to change it:

```
c:\>boot2docker init
Virtual machine boot2docker-vm already exists
c:\>boot2docker up
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
..........ooo
Started.
Writing C:\Users\xyz\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\ca.pem
Writing C:\Users\xyz\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\cert.pem
Writing C:\Users\xyz\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\key.pem
Docker client does not run on Windows for now. Please use
    "boot2docker.exe" ssh
to SSH into the VM instead.
c:\>boot2docker ssh -L 0.0.0.0:8000:localhost:8000
                        ##        .
                  ## ## ##       ==
               ## ## ## ##      ===
           /""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o          __/
             \    \        __/
              \____\______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
Boot2Docker version 1.3.2, build master : 495c19a - Mon Nov 24 20:40:58 UTC 2014
Docker version 1.3.2, build 39fa2fa
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker run -it -p 0.0.0.0:8000:80 --name imgcon33 img33/img33
```

This setup maps your application like this:
imgcon33 (port 80) -> docker (8000) -> boot2docker (8000) -> localhost (8000)

If you run curl from boot2docker, then a simple

```
curl localhost:80
```

should be enough.
But if you want to access your application from host container (the one that hosts boot2docker), you have to run it as

```
curl localhost:8000
```

Comment: Thanks Magic Wand for immediate reply... Now I tried with curl 192.168.56.101:49318(Here I created another container). But I'm getting this error:                      curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.56.101:49318; Connection refused

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I did not see how you created SSH connection with boot2docker, so I added my own setup.

Comment: Thank you @Magic Wand. Now I'm facing another one that is I wrote **CMD ["java", "-jar", "dockertest.jar"]** in Dokerfile. Now the container is getting exited always after each **docker start <Container ID>**. Can't I make container up always if I wrote CMD command. Would you please help me.

Comment: You can try to run it manually from bash and see if it works for you: "docker run -it <Container ID> /bin/bash". Could it be because you did not define full Java path? Try with CMD ["/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "dockertest.jar"].