# How to specify trigger to an image in Docker to automatically upload the image to Docker Hub after each build?

Tags: boot2docker, dockerhub

I'm very new to Docker.
I followed the automated build same as from
[Docker hub builds](http://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/) but I am getting the following error:
**Specified Dockerfile was not found. (/tmp/build_b3ybvmbgjtupwyx44drm4di/Dockerfile)**
Please help me to solve this........

Comment: I would suggest you contact support@docker.com - please include your hub account and repo details.

Comment: Thank you I found the solution.

Comment: @sivaodugu what's the soln?

Comment: @Adrian   Solution is at the following link                                                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124897/how-to-create-image-with-my-new-jar-file-in-docker/27145234?noredirect=1#comment42963948_27145234